# Calling window.print() closes the open socket connection whereas ctrl + p works just fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which contains in it a button to print the contents, with an onClick which calls window.print(), something like below (I have removed all the irrelevant code).

```
class HeaderComponent extends PureComponent {

  handlePrintAll = () => {
    window.print();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="p10 show-hidden" key="print" onClick= 
        {this.handlePrintAll}>
          <a className="cursor inblock">
            <svg className="is-24 sameline alignmiddle"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<use 
            xlink:href="/images/sprite-new.svg#print" />' }}/>
            <span className="inb-vmid  ml10 mr10">Print</span>
          </a>
        </span>
        <PrintTemplate />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

However, whenever I click the aforementioned button, and subsequently the print window pops up, the existing open socket connection, which is something the app uses, disconnects, after I do nothing for a minute or two and just keep the print preview window open. However, this issue does not occur when the same print window is brought up using the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>), and let sit idle for the same duration or even longer. Have tried removing the helper library I am using to style components differently for print, but to no avail. The issue apparently doesn't stem from the print helper, which is 'react-print' in this case, but window.print() itself.

And, nowhere does this whole file or component use the open socket connection in any way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: At a guess, I assume that `window.print()` is a blocking call - your JS may simply stop executing at that point while the window remains open.  I guess you have keepalives etc in your socket that timeout after a while?

Comment: Hmm, [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#printing) says _"The user agent **may** wait for the user to either accept or decline before returning"_ (my emphasis).  So in some browsers it might work, or in different versions of the same browser depending on how they're implemented.  Not sure how to work around this one...